# jquery variable inside live function not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this piece of code

```
$('ul.fonts li', '#wizard').live('click', function(e){
$('ul.fonts li', '#wizard').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$('blockquote').css('font-family', $(this).find('a').attr("class") )
e.preventDefault();
})
```

I tried ti optimize this code storing the selector in a variable.

```
var $fonts_links = $('ul.fonts li', '#wizard')
$fonts_links.live('click', function(e){
$fonts_links.removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$('blockquote').css('font-family', $(this).find('a').attr("class") )
e.preventDefault();
})
```

It works, except from the third line. `$fonts_links.removeClass('selected');
This is so weird..some advice?

Comment: _"It works, except from the third line."_ In what exactly way it doen't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've said *"It works, except [for] the third line."* but you haven't said *how* it doesn't work.

But since the whole point of [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is to handle your changing the DOM dynamically, you probably don't want to cache the result of the selector in this situation: If you add more list items after you've cached the result, they won't be added to the jQuery instance you've cached, and so you'll end up missing those ones out (not removing the "selected" class from them) when the handler next runs. So if that's what you're seeing...

If the `wizard` element is stable (not dynamic), you could do this:

```
var $wizard = $('#wizard');
$wizard.delegate('ul.fonts li', 'click', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    $wizard.find('ul.fonts li').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');
    $('blockquote').css('font-family', $this.find('a').attr("class") )
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

That way, you're only caching the stable bit, and you're explicitly telling jQuery what the root of the delegation is by using [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (which is a variant of `live` that's rooted in a specific element).

**Off-topic**: Unless you're seeing a performance problem with the original code in the wild, caching may not be your friend anyway — caching is a trade-off between memory use (and complexity) vs. speed-of-execution, probably best to only use it when faced with a tangible problem. But I'm assuming you're doing this for a reason, hence the suggestion above.

Comment: However you could cache `$(this)` within the `click` handler, since there's no need to build the same jQuery object twice => `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just started to use caching in Jquery

Comment: @Peter: Can and should, I didn't notice he was using it twice. Fixed, thanks.